# How to improve view of outlinedbutton in compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, colors, android-jetpack-compose

I have problem with darkmode and my background when I click on element and it is focused.
I can't find which of this change this background of E-mail text label?

```
class TextFieldColors internal constructor(
    private val focusedTextColor: Color,
    private val unfocusedTextColor: Color,
    private val disabledTextColor: Color,
    private val errorTextColor: Color,
    private val focusedContainerColor: Color,
    private val unfocusedContainerColor: Color,
    private val disabledContainerColor: Color,
    private val errorContainerColor: Color,
    private val cursorColor: Color,
    private val errorCursorColor: Color,
    private val textSelectionColors: TextSelectionColors,
    private val focusedIndicatorColor: Color,
    private val unfocusedIndicatorColor: Color,
    private val disabledIndicatorColor: Color,
    private val errorIndicatorColor: Color,
    private val focusedLeadingIconColor: Color,
    private val unfocusedLeadingIconColor: Color,
    private val disabledLeadingIconColor: Color,
    private val errorLeadingIconColor: Color,
    private val focusedTrailingIconColor: Color,
    private val unfocusedTrailingIconColor: Color,
    private val disabledTrailingIconColor: Color,
    private val errorTrailingIconColor: Color,
    private val focusedLabelColor: Color,
    private val unfocusedLabelColor: Color,
    private val disabledLabelColor: Color,
    private val errorLabelColor: Color,
    private val focusedPlaceholderColor: Color,
    private val unfocusedPlaceholderColor: Color,
    private val disabledPlaceholderColor: Color,
    private val errorPlaceholderColor: Color,
    private val focusedSupportingTextColor: Color,
    private val unfocusedSupportingTextColor: Color,
    private val disabledSupportingTextColor: Color,
    private val errorSupportingTextColor: Color,
    private val focusedPrefixColor: Color,
    private val unfocusedPrefixColor: Color,
    private val disabledPrefixColor: Color,
    private val errorPrefixColor: Color,
    private val focusedSuffixColor: Color,
    private val unfocusedSuffixColor: Color,
    private val disabledSuffixColor: Color,
    private val errorSuffixColor: Color,
) {
```

[image: outlined]

I have tested almost all of them and I can't find it.

EDIT:
Change this black background color it should be transparent.
[image]

EXAMPLE:

```
  textFieldDefault: TextFieldColors = OutlinedTextFieldDefaults.colors(
        disabledTextColor = Color.Gray,
        focusedContainerColor = Color.White,
        unfocusedContainerColor = Color.White,
        disabledContainerColor = Color.White,
        focusedSuffixColor = Color.Green,
        cursorColor = Color.Black,
        disabledBorderColor = if (isInputError) Color.Red else Color.Gray,
        disabledLabelColor = Color.Blue,
    ),
    textFieldError: TextFieldColors = OutlinedTextFieldDefaults.colors(
        errorBorderColor = Color.Red,
        unfocusedLeadingIconColor = Color.Red,
        focusedLeadingIconColor = Color.Red,
        cursorColor = Color.Gray,
        focusedBorderColor = Color.Red,
        unfocusedBorderColor = Color.Red
    ),

    OutlinedTextField(
        value = value,
        onValueChange = {
            onValueChange(it)
        },
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        colors = if (!isInputError) textFieldDefault else textFieldError,
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
        singleLine = true,
    [...]
```

it is code because I mostly ask for code help.

Comment: What would your desired output look like? Do you want to change the outline of the text input when it is focused?

Comment: yes I want to change it when it is focused, normally it is on the right of the email icon like: Icon "E-mail" when it is focused it goes like this, but the background of E-mail looks bad and I cant change it

Comment: Do you want to change the color of the outline or the color of the icon? You are saying two different things. Or do you want the text "E-mail" to be colored differently?

Comment: Thanks for answer  I have edited my post. Look at the screen

Comment: Can you share the code you have right now for the text input and what you tried exactly?

Comment: yes please see edited post

Comment: and can you help me with that?